# IllegalArgumentException: Type specified for TypedQuery [model.User] is incompatible with query return type [class model.User]

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I am getting this intermittent error while creating a TypedQuery for Generic type. My method is as:

```
    public List<T> findByEmail(Class type, String email_id){
        String query = "SELECT t FROM " + type.getSimpleName() + " t WHERE t.email =:"+email_id;
        TypedQuery<T> typedQuery =em.createQuery(query, type);
        return (List<T>) typedQuery.getResultList();            
   }
```

While if I restart the server, the error doesn't reappear and it correctly fetch result.

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[IllegalArgumentException: Type specified for TypedQuery [model.User] is incompatible with query return type [class model.User]]]
            at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:296) ~[play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
            at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:402) [play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
            at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun
    $applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:
    2.3.7]
            at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun
    $applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
            at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type specified for TypedQuery [model.User] is incompatible with query return type [class model.User]
            at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.resultClassChecking(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:387) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
            at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractE
    ntityManagerImpl.java:344) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final
    ]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.
    0_25]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
    java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
    sorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
```

Comment: Your problem may be in older deployment which exists in server. Why you are using StringBuilder in this code?

Comment: Nothing specific to use StringBuilder, updated code with String also it's the same. Seems to be an issue with in Classloading, but not sure what.

Comment: I see the problem is related with play framework, which its hot deploy feature relies on creating child class loaders for every reload. The class you are passing as parameter seems to have been loaded by a previous class loader instance so now Class<model.User> != Class<model.User>

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is

```
TypedQuery<T> typedQuery =em.createQuery(query.toString(), type);
```

Here var type is a Class Object not the User class, you need to do something like this.

```
TypedQuery<T> typedQuery =em.createQuery(query.toString(), Class.forName(type.getSimpleName()));
```

this will return a Class and  TypedQuery will become  TypedQuery in runtime

Comment: type is Class here, passed as 'User.class'.